# What is the derivation for the derivative of $a^{t}$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Been driving me nuts.  Can someone prove to me that

$$\frac{d(a^t)}{dt} = a^t \ln(a)$$

Thank you!

Comment: Two posted answers below explain how to get this if you _already_ know what the answer is when $a=e$.  My answer and one other explain how to differentiate exponential functions in general when that is not yet known.  My answer refers to other answers for the part about the chain rule.  I also point out what is "natural" about the number $e$ and why the meaning of the word "constant" is sometimes a bit subtler than it may superficially appear.

Comment: ah yes good to point that out @MichaelHardy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express $a^t$ as $e^{\ln a^t}$, leading to
$$\frac{d(a^t)}{dt}=\frac{d(e^{\ln a^{t}})}{dt}=\frac{d(e^{t\ln a})}{dt}=(\ln a)(e^{t\ln a})=(\ln a)(e^{\ln a^{t}})=a^t\ln a$$

This works because by taking the $\ln(a^t)$ then raising $e^{\ln a^{t}} =a^{t}$ as such you are not changing the nature of the function.

Comment: This of course assumes it is _already_ known that $(d/dt)e^t=e^t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: How do you justify your first and your third equation where you substitute “$a^t$” by “$\ln a^t$” and then “$t \ln a$” by “$e^{t \ln a}$”? (I’d just have jumped from the first term to the fourth with no intermediate steps using your argument below.)

Comment: @k.stm an intermediate edit was made to my original answer, which I have rectified.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Yes, in my answer I have assumed that the differential of $e^t$ is known.

Answer (score 3):

Use the definition(!) $$a^t:=e^{t\ln a}$$

Comment: This assumes it is _already_ known how to differentiate $t\mapsto e^t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

You know  that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = \log{a}$$, then

$$\frac{d}{dt} a^t = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^{t+h}-a^t}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} a^t\frac{a^h-1}{h} = a^t \log{a}$$

Comment: Is there an elementary proof for the first identity?

Comment: @k.stm since $e = \lim_{h \to 0} (1 + \frac 1h)^\frac 1h \Rightarrow e^h \sim 1 + h$ and then $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h} = 1$. 
Hence, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h -1}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{h \log a} - 1}{h \log a} \log a = \log a$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{d(a^x)}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta(a^x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{a^{x+\Delta x}-a^x}{\Delta x} & =\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\left(a^x \frac{a^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}\right) \\[18pt]
& = a^x \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{a^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}\quad\ldots\ldots
\end{align}
This last step works because $a$ is "constant" and "constant" means not depending on $\Delta x$, i.e. not changing as $\Delta x$ changes.
$$
\cdots\cdots = \left(a^x\cdot \text{constant}\right) \quad \ldots\ldots
$$
and *this* time "constant" means not depending on $x$.

If $a=e$ then this last "constant" is $1$.  That is what is "natural" about $e$.

To find the "constant" in other cases, use the chain rule and the laws of exponents.  Others have posted the details of that step here.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative proof via implicit differentiation:
Let $y=a^t.$

Taking (natural) logs of both sides, yielding: $\ln(y)=\ln(a^t)\iff \ln(y)=t\ln(a)$ (using the power rule for logarithms).

Now, differentiate both sides wrt $t$, as follows: $\underbrace{\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}}_{\text{using chain rule}}=\ln(a)\iff\frac{dy}{dt}=y\ln(a)=\underbrace{a^t\ln(a)}_{\text{since }y:=a^t}$.